# codeception functional tests gives 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, codeception

i'm just trying to run a simple functional test but codeception fails the test saying http code is 500.

i am new to php, wordpress and codeception. tried to see why 500 code, but looks like the request is not received at my localhost apache server. not sure why codeception treats it as 500 response code.

below is my simple test.

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Functional;
class AddRequestCest {
    /**
     * It should store last operation result
     * @test
     *
     *
     */
    public function return_the_correct_result( \FunctionalTester $I) {

        // $I->amOnPage( "/wp-json/calc/add/{$first}/{$second}" );
        $I->amOnPage( "/" );

        $I->seeResponseCodeIs( 200 );
        $I->seeOptionInDatabase( [ 'option_name' => '_transient_last_operation' ] );
    }
}
```

failure is

```
Functional Tests (1) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: \Helper\Functional, Filesystem, WPDb, WordPress, WPLoader
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AddRequestCest: Return_the_correct_result | 5,4
Signature: Tests\Functional\AddRequestCest:return_the_correct_result
Test: tests/functional/AddRequestCest.php:return_the_correct_result
Scenario --
 I am on page "/"
  [Cookie Jar] ["wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/; httponly"]
  [Request Headers] []
  [Page] /
  [Response] 500
  [Request Cookies] {"wordpress_test_cookie":"WP Cookie check"}
  [Response Headers] {"Content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","Set-Cookie":["wordpress_test_cookie=WP Cookie check"]}
 I see response code is 200
 FAIL 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 1.62 seconds, Memory: 30.00MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) AddRequestCest: Return_the_correct_result | 5,4
 Test  tests/functional/AddRequestCest.php:return_the_correct_result
 Step  See response code is 200
 Fail  Expected HTTP Status Code: 200 (OK). Actual Status Code: 500 (Internal Server Error)
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

Scenario Steps:

 2. $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200) at tests/functional/AddRequestCest.php:18
 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests/functional/AddRequestCest.php:16


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

---

functional.yml file

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration

# Suite for WordPress functional tests.
# Emulate web requests and make the WordPress application process them.


class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Filesystem
        - WPDb
        - WordPress
        - WPLoader
    config:
        WPDb:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=wpTests'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'root'
            dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
            url: 'http://localhost/wordpress'
            urlReplacement: true
            tablePrefix: 'wp_'
        WordPress:
            depends: WPDb
            wpRootFolder: '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress'
            adminUsername: 'admin'
            adminPassword: 'admin'
            adminPath: '/wp-admin'
        WPLoader:
            loadOnly: true
            wpRootFolder: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress"
            dbName: "wpTests"
            dbHost: "127.0.0.1"
            dbUser: "root"
            dbPassword: "root"
            title: "HelloWorld"
            plugins: ['rest-calculator/rest-calculator.php']
            activatePlugins: ['rest-calculator/rest-calculator.php']
```

Comment: It looks like you missed url parameter of WordPress module. https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser#wpbrowser-configuration

Comment: thanks for your reply. i could see "Wordpress" module has no such parameter. do i need to add "WpBrowser" to my config ? i'm trying to run tests for this example project of codeception - https://github.com/lucatume/rest-calculator and using the same configuration. please help.

Comment: It is best to raise an issue at https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser/issues